# How to display QVector3D in one cell in QTableView via qAbstractTableModel's subclass

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtableview, qvector3d

I'd like to display QVector3D in tableView, preferably like this: (x,y,z).
I had subclassed the QAbstractTableModel class and implemented QAbstractTableModelSublass::data function:

```
QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role= Qt::DisplayRole) const override
{
  ...
  if(role == Qt::DisplayRole)
  {  /* decide in which column and row to display the data*/
    QVector3D p(1.,2.,3.); return QVariant(p); 
  }
}
```

However, the target cell where the QVector3D should be displayed is empty. I'm quite positive that the correct QVariant instance is constructed, since I was able to print the value like this:

```
QVariant v = QVariant(p);
qDebug()<<v.value<QVector3D>();
```

What am I missing? How am I supposed to display the QVector3D in table in one cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Qt::DisplayRole` requires a QString in the variant, but you are providing a QVector3D. There is no conversion from QVector3D to QString in QVariant (see [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#toString)).

You should either convert the Vector to a string representation yourself, or use a [`QStyledItemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html) to override the `displayText` method for converting QVector3D to a string representations.

NB: Your debug output works, because there is a dedicated `QDebug operator<<(QDebug dbg, const QVector3D &vector)` for printing QVector3D in QDebug

Comment: QStyledItemDelegate::displayText is not even called (called qDebug in fn body) when QVector3D is (0,0,0). Meaning, nothing is displayed. Everything is fine when at least one component is not zero.  If I don't use delegate and return QString in data() fn as  described below in vahancho's answer, the value is displayed as expected. What kind of sorcery is this?

Answer (score 3):

I would do it in the following way:

```
QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role= Qt::DisplayRole) const
{
  ...
  if(role == Qt::DisplayRole)
  {  /* decide in which column and row to display the data*/
    QVector3D p(1.,2.,3.);
    return QString("(%1, %2, %3)").arg(p.x()).arg(p.y()).arg(p.z()); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, in that case, if the model is editable, I suppose that should provide a validator?

Comment: Yes, you should validated the input string in the form of "(x, y, z)" or other, parse it and construct new QVector3D.